# Conjugacy Classes in Finite Nilpotent Group

Tags: group-theory

I have been doing some studying and I was wondering if there was any literature regarding the conjugacy classes size in a finite nilpotent group in determining if a group is a p-group or not.  It seems to be that there is not; I was wondering if anyone knew of any literature (I can not seem to locate anything through online resources and my library). If there is no literature I am curious as to why because it seems that this would be a studied question.

EDIT: To be more precise. The question is Let G be finite nilpotent group. Given the largest class size can one determine if G is of prime power order.

Comment: I don't think so, if I understand the question correctly.  Suppose that $G = P\times H$, with $P$ (for instance) a non-abelian $3$-group, and $H$ an abelian $2$-group.  Then $G$ is nilpotent, not a $p$-group, for any $p$, and the largest class size in $G$ is the same as the largest class size in $P$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by using the sizes of conjugacy classes to determine if a group is a $p$-group, but it's a standard theorem that finite nilpotent groups are precisely those groups which are a product of their Sylow subgroups, i.e., a product of $p$-groups.

Moreover, the conjugacy classes of $A \times B$ for $A, B$ groups are precisely the pairs of conjugacy classes of $A$ and $B$. So for a nilpotent group, the sizes of the conjugacy classes that you get will be the product of the sizes for each $p$-group.

Does that help answer your question?

***Edit***: James has pointed out that you cannot characterize the $p$-groups using only the *set* of cardinalities of conjugacy classes. I'll just add that if you record the *multiset* of cardinalities of conjugacy classes, then obviously you can add them up to get the order of the group.

Comment: My question is incredibly unclear, I am sorry for that. I will edit my question to make it more precise and try to be more clear.